# why Label on Xamarin.forms does not display all text?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am trying to display almost 300 lines on one page using `label` control, but i only showing first top lines, i am using the following code, how i can display all lines, is `label` the appropriate controls?

```
 Label testt = new Label { Text = MainPage.part1, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, FontSize = 24, TextColor = Color.White };         
            StackLayout stacklayout = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                    TitleOfBook,                     
                    testt

                }
            };
            ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView
            {
                Content = stacklayout
                ,VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };
            Content = scroll;
```

Comment: No, a Label is not the approriate control for displaying 300 lines of text.  An Editor or even a WebView would be a much better choice.

Comment: @jason Text color display as gray when using editor ..:(

Comment: WebView  was much better choice for me ..thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across a similar problem a while back.  I believe the issue was that the label has a limit of 100 lines (or something along those lines).  You can create a custom label and set the line limit to be higher.

Here is a link to the [Xamarin Forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/26611/label-display-problem) topic which may be able to give you an idea of implementation.

Comment: i see your links and i use the code .and set maxline to 1000 but it still display only top 100 line ?!

Comment: how i can use LongLabelRenderer ?

Comment: i know this is a bit old but `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(LongLabelRenderer))]` this will make it that u use the renderer